# Crash in runtime in Razor while using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to show multiple lists thru ViewModel. Currently started with one, but I'm getting the following runtime error:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'allLocationBasedPromotions

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FreeRolla.BaseObjects
{
    class LocationBasedPromotion
    {
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string FlagIcon { get; set; }
    public int HotelCount { get; set; }
    public int StartingPrice { get; set; }
    public string WeatherIcon { get; set; }
    public string WeatherTemperature { get; set; }
    public string CityImage { get; set; }
    public List<LocationBasedPromotion> Promotions { get; set; }
}
}



using FreeRolla.BaseObjects;

namespace FreeRolla.BL
{
class HPLocationBasedPromotionProvider
{
    public List<LocationBasedPromotion> GetAllPromotions()
    {
        return new List<LocationBasedPromotion>{
            new LocationBasedPromotion{Country="UK", City="London", FlagIcon="", HotelCount=135, StartingPrice=350, CityImage="London.jpg", WeatherIcon="cloudy", WeatherTemperature="+18" },
            new LocationBasedPromotion{Country="Spain", City="Barcelona", FlagIcon="", HotelCount=215, StartingPrice=230, CityImage="Barcelona.jpg", WeatherIcon="sunny", WeatherTemperature="+28" },
            new LocationBasedPromotion{Country="Israel", City="Tel-Aviv", FlagIcon="", HotelCount=75, StartingPrice=280, CityImage="Tel-Aviv.jpg", WeatherIcon="sunny", WeatherTemperature="+32" }
        };
    }
}
}


using FreeRolla.BaseObjects;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace FreeRolla.Models.ViewModels
{
class HomeView 
{
    public List<LocationBasedPromotion> allLocationBasedPromotions { get; set; }
}
}


using FreeRolla.BL;
using FreeRolla.Models.ViewModels;

namespace FreeRolla.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //return View();
        HPLocationBasedPromotionProvider _BigPromotions = new HPLocationBasedPromotionProvider();
        HomeView hv = new HomeView();
        hv.allLocationBasedPromotions = _BigPromotions.GetAllPromotions();
        return View(hv);
    }
}
```

}

From the view - here the crash is occures:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.allLocationBasedPromotions)
```

{

Comment: Can you show the view? Were you able to catch the exception while debugging? If so, where exactly did it occur?

Comment: It looks like you either wrongly typed your view or passed wrong model or none at all.

Comment: Based on that error, it looks like you have some reference issues going on, but I would assume your `HomeView` class is in the same project/namespace as your `HomeController` class.

Comment: Thanks your help. I've updated the question with namespaces and the razor where the crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Might be too obvious, but looks like your view file is missing this

`@model FreeRolla.Models.ViewModels.HomeView`

EDIT:

Your view class should have the following declaration:

```
namespace FreeRolla.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeView
    {
        public List<LocationBasedPromotion> allLocationBasedPromotions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The class `LocationBasedPromotion` should also be made `public`. Basically, as a tip, make every class `public` in your project, unless you have a good reason not too. As you gain more experience, you will encounter situations where you'll know when not to make a class `public`. But in your case, just make them `public`.

Comment: just added it at the first line of View. Getting the following error:  CS0122: 'FreeRolla.Models.ViewModels.HomeView' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Change the declaration to `public class HomeView`

Comment: did that. Now I'm getting: Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FreeRolla.BaseObjects.LocationBasedPromotion>' is less accessible than property 'FreeRolla.Models.ViewModels.HomeView.allLocationBasedPromotions'